# Let X be a subset of R be a countable set. Show that there exists an x in R such that E intersect (E+x) is the empty set.

Tags: real-analysis

I am very confused by this. If E is countable then E+x would be countable and then E intersection with E+x would just be E right??? I am very confused and could use some guidance.

Comment: In title it says $X$ is countable, says nothing about $E.$ Yet after "I am confused" you say "if $E$ is countable". Why?

Comment: Presumably $E+x$ means $\{e+x:e\in E\}$, not $E\cup\{x\}$

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the $X$ in the title was supposed to be $E$.

$E\cap(E+x)=E$ if and only if $x=0$, so no, it’s not generally true that it’s equal to $E$, and in fact you want to show that if $E$ is countable, there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $E\cap(E+x)=\varnothing$.

To do this, you should ask yourself exactly what it means for some real number $y$ to be in $E\cap(E+x)$. In order for that to be the case, we must have $y\in E$ and $y\in E+x$. In other words, not only is $y\in E$, but there is some $e\in E$ such that $y=e+x$, or in other words, $x=y-e$. In short, $E\cap(E+x)\ne\varnothing$ if and only if there are $y,e\in E$ such that $y-e=x$. If we could find a read number $x$ that was not the difference of any two members of $E$, we’d know that $E\cap(E+x)=\varnothing$.

Now use the fact that $E$ is countable to explain why there must be a real number $x$ that is not the difference of any two members of $E$. (In fact there must be lots of them.)

Comment: Thanks very much! That helped a lot!

Comment: @Anna If you think it helps a lot, then you should accept the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and perhaps upvote https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up .

Comment: @Anna: You’re very welcome.